# The user hdfs is missing in its own group

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I recently installed Cloudera and after doing installation, I ran the host inspector. But I saw some messages in it (screenshot attached). Please let me know how to get rid of them. Also, is the cluster good to use?

[image: Host Inspector]

I have installed cloudera using root user.

Comment: Can you check the details with "View Details" and check whether the users are missing on server where the corresponding service is supposed to run? For example: is the user "hue" available on the machine where the service "HUE" is supposed to run? Maybe the message is just telling you "The user is not on the other machines, so you couldn't move the service if you wanted to.", which would explain why it's a warning and not an error.

Comment: Any update on this issue. I keep getting this error.